# Работа с indexes при использовании Spring boot + Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

Мне известно, что я могу создать индекс как на один столбец, так сделать и составной. A также я могу составить индекс на некоторое выражение:

- создать индекс на выражение, которое ищет по некоторому условию данные, при этом сначала я указываю что поля сначала нужно отсортировать и затем по условию вывести результат и вот основе этого выражения, строиться индекс.

(Наподобие использования индекса при работе с Couchbase)

```sql
CREATE INDEX `us_users_sorted` ON
`user_profile`(
    `_class`,
    `enabled`,
    `countryCode`,
    `firstName` DESC,
    `lastName` DESC)
WHERE (((`_class` = "com.cb.demo.userProfile.model.UserEntity")
    and (`enabled` = true))
    and (`countryCode` = "US"))
```

Но я не могу найти информацию вот о чем :

1. Если я буду создавать запись, я снова должен буду вызывать в этой же транзакции создание индекса для этих данных (индекс описан выше) ?
2. При удалении записи я то же должен буду снова вызвать создание заново этого индекса ?
3. При обновлении я то же должен буду это делать ?
4. Я это должен делать через nativeQuery() , если я использую Spring Data Jpa ?

Выделить это в несколько вопросов не вижу смысла, по факту это вопрос о работе с индексами используя Spring и реляционную базу данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут есть недопонимание, как работают индексы в реляционной БД.

Вы создаете индекс один раз, и потом он автоматически изменяется при изменении таблицы. Т.е. при создании/изменении/удалении записи в таблице индекс будет автоматически изменен самой БД (если это полный индекс или если запись попадает под условие частичного индекса). Вам ничего дополнительно делать не нужно.

То есть с вашей стороны нужно только сконфигурировать (создать) индекс. Делается это в зависимости от инструментов, которые вы используете для создания структоры БД. Так как частичные индексы поддерживаются далеко не всеми БД, в JPA нет возможности сконфигурировать такой индекс стандартным способом. С помощью аннотаций JPA можно задавать только обычные индексы.

При использовании spring нужно сделать миграцию БД с созданием индекса вручную. Наверное, самый простой способ это  сделать - это использовать [инструменты миграции](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool), которые поддерживает spring: flyway или liquibase.